# Joomla article not showing in the frontend but its visible in administrative part

Tags: php, joomla

I have a very big article to be put into our joomla site. At first I was getting "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 8388608 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 285487 bytes) in..." . But then I increased the memory_limit in php.ini . And I was able to create the article. Now I can view the article by logging into backend. But the article is not at all visible in the front end. If I click on the menu item pointing to that article, all I can see is a blank page with nothing in it. All other articles in the site are visible properly. Any idea?

ps: I have enabled the error reporting to maximum, also ran the site in debugging mode. But saw nothing unusual.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have rights to show it outside the company.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put in a very lagre picture?
This can exceed your memory

Comment: No picture. I just put some tables. It actually exceeded the default memory size limit. Thats why I increased the memory limit from php.ini. Now article is ready, but it can only be viewed in backend. Is there a separate memory limiting parameter for frontend too?

Answer (score 0):

Could be a database problem, or maybe an upload issue?

Comment: It can't be an upload issue as I mentioned that article is already created. So there's nothing to be uploaded. Please read the question

Comment: Can you check the php ini settings are taking effect? Look in the backend under Help > System Info > PHP Information